# Select statement based on posted data from dropbox box

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, pdo

I'm working on a small website and I'm currently stuck on a small issue.
Ive got a set of dropdown boxes created and populated in HTML, for example:

```
<select name="heatingType" id="heatingType" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Option</option>
          <option value = "Gas">Gas</option>
          <option value = "Electricity">Electricity</option>
          <option value = "Other">Other</option>          
    </select>
```

I'm able to store the values in a variable once the form has been posted/submitted, These are stored in my Controller Class eg:

```
    $newCalc = new ConCalc();
    // instantiate drawing tool
    $draw = new DrawTool();
    // parse (render) appliance view
    $renderedView = $draw->render('../View/calculator.php', array('calcvalues' => $newCalc->getValues()));
    if(isset($_POST['btn-calcCon'])){
            $heatType = $_POST['heatingType'];
            $meterType = $_POST['meterType'];
            $bedrooms = $_POST['noBedrooms'];
            $house = $_POST['houseType'];
            $age = $_POST['houseAge'];
                echo $heatType;
                echo $meterType;
                echo $bedrooms;
                echo $house;
                echo $age;
        }
    echo $renderedView;
```

If i echo out any of the varibales then it will display the value that was selected and posted in that dropdown.

My table structure is as follows:

```
HeatingType     MeterType   Bedrooms    HouseType   HouseAge              Consumption
Gas             Standard    1 or 2     Flat          Less than 11 years     5430
Gas             Standard    1 or 2     Flat          More than 11 years     7270
```

So for example, if i chose Gas, Standard, 1 or 2, Flat and Less than 11 then i should have 5430 returned.

Now the problem I'm facing is how to use these posted values in a select statement,
I know i need to do something along the lines of :

```
SELECT Consumption fron ConTable WHERE HeatingType LIKE heatingTypeDropdownValue AND MeterType LIKE MeterTypeDropDownValue etc etc.
```

but im not exactly sure 
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a session array:

```
`$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
$_SESSION['post-data']['heatingType'];
$_SESSION['post-data']['meterType'];
$_SESSION['post-data']['noBedrooms'];
$_SESSION['post-data']['houseType'];
$_SESSION['post-data']['houseAge'];`
```

And then using `$_SESSION['post-data']['heatingType']` In the where clause